# ssrs expression based on parameter changing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-expression

I have two parameters in my chart report A and B.
In the series group of chart I have field colour with three colour names("red","green","brown").

Here I need to write an expression when the parameter is "A", I should only see "red",Green" values in the field colour and if it is Parameter "B", I should see all the three colours.

I tried different expressing using

```
=iif(Parameters!channel.Value="A" and Fields!COLOUR.Value="BROWN",O,Fields!COLOUR.Value)
```

But by writing this expression I can convert "brown" to zero value but I am not able to hide it.

Any help plz?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this expression on field color:

```
"Red, Green"+ iif(Parameters!channel.Value="A", ", Brown","")
```

`+` is used for concatenating two strings.

[image]

As put forward,`&` is a better option for concatenating.

```
"Red, Green" & iif(Parameters!channel.Value="A", ", Brown","")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But still the expression is not working

Comment: Where are you putting the expression, may I know?

Comment: You need to atleast replace "+" with "&" to concate strings in SSRS expressions

Comment: @TomiNiemenmaa - For your benefit I will attach a screenshot in my answer. It should be +, not &. (BTW, I am using SSRS 2012, but I hope it's the same in 2008 as well)

Comment: I am putting the expression  in the label field inside the category group properties. I also tried using this expression =Fields!colour.Value="red","green" +iif(Parameters!channel.Value="A",Fields!Application.Value="BROWN","").

Comment: What is the problem you are are facing? It should work perfectly.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti - In fact, both `+` and `&` can concatenate two strings, but `&` is recommended by MSDN ([+ Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)). `When you use the + operator, you might not be able to determine whether addition or string concatenation will occur. Use the & operator for concatenation to eliminate ambiguity and to provide self-documenting code.`